# Logic app Error FTP server xxx.xxx.xxx is currently unavaible

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps, paas

I am using logic app to upload some files from the blob storage to FTP. Most of the time my logic app fails states that Error FTP server xxx.xxx.xxx  is currently unavailable. Sometimes it went successfull.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "logic-apis-eastus.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 502,
      "message": "The FTP server 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is currently unavailable. Please verify server logs to troubleshoot connection issues.\r\nclientRequestId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "error": {
        "message": "The FTP server 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is currently unavailable. Please verify server logs to troubleshoot connection issues."
      },
      "source": "ftp-eus.azconn-eus.p.azurewebsites.net"
    }
  }
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening my number of records 2500 or more than that.

Can anyone advice on that what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

502 Bad gateway is due to connectivity or network failures. If the transmission takes more than 110 seconds also we will get this error. Its better to check FTP server logs during that time and perhaps check fiddler traces too. 
If nothing worked you can raise a support request to Microsoft.

Comment: Hello Haris you are correct there is some limitations in logic app in order to upload the files to ftp , I will be checking with MS ticket.